# Should we use max.poll.records or max.poll.interval.ms to handle records that take longer to process in kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to understand what is better option to handle records that take longer to process in kafka consumer? I ran few tests to understand this and observed that we can control this with by modifying either `max.poll.records` or `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Now my question is, what's the better option to choose? Please suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`max.poll.records` simply defines the maximum number of records returned in a single call to `poll()`.

Now `max.poll.interval.ms` defines the delay between the calls to `poll()`.

> `max.poll.interval.ms:` The maximum delay between invocations of
>   `poll()` when using consumer group management. This places an upper
>   bound on the amount of time that the consumer can be idle before
>   fetching more records. **If `poll()` is not called before expiration of
>   this timeout, then the consumer is considered failed and the group
>   will rebalance in order to reassign the partitions to another member**.
>   For consumers using a non-null `group.instance.id` which reach this
>   timeout, partitions will not be immediately reassigned. Instead, the
>   consumer will stop sending heartbeats and partitions will be
>   reassigned after expiration of `session.timeout.ms`. This mirrors the
>   behavior of a static consumer which has shutdown.

---

I believe you can tune both in order to get to the expected behaviour. For example, you could compute the average processing time for the messages. If the average processing time is say 1 second and you have `max.poll.records=100` then you should allow approximately 100+ seconds for the poll interval.

Comment: Thanks for the response, we are tuning both in order to get to the expected behavior  and I'm curious to know what's the better option. and trying to understand if there is limit on setting the max.poll.interval.ms

Comment: @Raj Yep. As I said you can actually tune both of them or just one of them. I would say you need to pay more attention to `max.poll.interval.ms` but as I mentioned the configuration is dependent to `max.poll.records`. So one possible plan could be to stick to a particular `max.poll.records` and then tune `max.poll.interval.ms` so that you get to the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

If you have slow processing and so want to avoid rebalances then tuning either would achieve that. However extending max.poll.interval.ms to allow for longer gaps between poll does have a bit of a side effect.

Each consumer only uses 2 threads - polling thread and heartbeat thread.

The latter lets the group know that your application is still alive so can trigger a rebalance before max.poll.interval.ms expires.

The polling thread does everything else in terms of group communication so during the poll method you find out if a rebalance has been triggered elsewhere, you find out if a partition leader has died and hence metadata refresh is required. The implication is that if you allow longer gaps between polls then the group as a whole is slower to respond to change (for example no consumers start receiving messages after a rebalance until they have all received their new partitions - if a rebalance occurs just after one consumer has started processing a batch for 10 minutes then all consumers will be hanging around for at least that long).

Hence for a more responsive group in situations where processing of messages is expected to be slow you should choose to reduce the records fetched in each batch.

Comment: Thanks Chris for you response. As per the confluent kafka definitive guide, session.timeout.ms controls how long a consumer can go without sending a heartbeat. Therefore, those two properties are typically modified together—heatbeat.interval.ms must be lower than session.timeout.ms, and is usually set to one-third of the timeout value.

Comment: Setting session.timeout.ms lower than the default will allow consumer groups to detect and recover from failure sooner, but may also cause unwanted rebalances as a result of consumers taking longer to complete the poll loop or garbage collection. Setting session.timeout.ms higher will reduce the chance of accidental rebalance, but also means it will take longer to detect a real failure.

Comment: so my understanding is, the rebalancing is coupled with session.timeout.ms and even that behavior  should change after the KIP-62 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread

Comment: As mentioned heartbeat is for quick detection if consumer death, and the 2 properties you mention relate to that. Your original question is more about poll timeout which is the other mechanism which prevents livelock where a consumer process is running but they aren't polling.